# Anyone recognise this court based film about a mute man accused of murder?

Tags: identify-this-movie

Does anyone recognise this film? I can only remember two scenes from it and the vague plot:

I watched it about 20 years ago on TV in the UK.  It is an American film, set in America.  I would guess it was made in the '60s.

A young girl is friends with a mute, white haired man, who is accused of murder.

Over dinner the girl asks her father, who is a lawyer, to help her friend when he goes to trial as she is sure he is innocent.  When she has gone to bed the father tells his wife he is going to help - the dialog is something like:

> Husband: "We have always told her to come to us if she needs help. She has come to us so I am going to help."

It goes to court and they take the decision to place the young girl on the stand as a witness.  The prosecuting lawyer tears into her and shouts something about the man sexually abusing her. The court goes mad.  People start shouting and throwing things, the defendent charges across the room to assault the lawyer, the girl runs from the stand in tears, her father runs to pick her up, police officers are running around trying to figure out who to arrest first as the judge shouts for order and bangs his hammer.

The defendant ends up on the stand but has to write all of his answers to the questions for the bailiff to read out. One question was:

> "Did you kill *name removed from my memory*?"
>   "No, he was my friend."

I know it is not much to go on - does it jog anyone's memory?

Comment: It's To Kill a Mockingbird

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but it is not that.  The girl has no brother and the defendant is white.  Racism is not an aspect of the film.

Comment: Could whomever downvoted leave a comment to let me know why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like [When Every Day was the Fourth of July](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_Every_Day_Was_the_Fourth_of_July), a 1978 NBC made-for-TV movie about a pair of youngsters who befriend a brain-damaged veteran in 1930's Connecticut. It has a little girl whose father is an attorney, and the description of the courtroom scene matches Wikipedia.

Comment: This sounds just like it!